# New modelAttribute is getting created for execution of each requestMapping method in controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following methods in my controller.

```
@ModelAttribute("myAttribute")
public MyAttribute getMyAttribute() {
    return new MyAttribute();
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String myHomePage(@ModelAttribute("myAttribute") MyAttribute myAttribute, Model model) {
    //some changes in model attribute
    model.addAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
    returns ("myFirstPageView");
}
@RequestMapping(value = {"/mySecondPage" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String mySecondPage(@ModelAttribute("myAttribute") MyAttribute myAttribute, Model model) {
    //some changes in model attribute
    model.addAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
    returns ("mySecondPageView");
}
```

After loading my first page, a button click will take user to second page via the method 
`@RequestMapping(value = {"/mySecondPage" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)`
But the problem is new model attribute is created when executing the second request mapping method.

I need the values set in model by the first request mapping method to be retained inside the second method also.

I know that this can be resolved by the following method

```
MyAttribute myAttribute;    

    @ModelAttribute("myAttribute")
    public MyAttribute getMyAttribute() {
        if(myAttribute==null)
        {
            myAttribute=new MyAttribute();
        }
        return  myAttribute;    
    }
```

But I am not supposed to use a class level variable. Please let me know if there is a way to overcome this without using class level variable.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a class level variable in a spring controller : as the controller is a singleton, the variable will be shared across every session !

There is a simple way to do what you want : just scope your model attribute in session. But **beware** even if you could find other posts saying that session attributes magically disappear when you no longer needs them it is false ! **You have to manually remove session attributes when done via SessionStatus.setComplete()**. (ref : the PetClinic example from Spring)

You could modify your controller the following way :

```
@SessionAttributes("myAttribute") // scopes myAttribute in session
public class myController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myHomePage(@ModelAttribute("myAttribute") MyAttribute myAttribute, Model model) {
        //some changes in model attribute
        model.addAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
        returns ("myFirstPageView");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/mySecondPage" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String mySecondPage(@ModelAttribute("myAttribute") MyAttribute myAttribute, Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        //some changes in model attribute
        model.addAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
        sessionStatus.setComplete(); // if this is the last usage of myAttribute
        returns ("mySecondPageView");
    }
}
```

In the above code, if you called successively `myHomePage`, all calls after the first will use the preceding `myAttribute` from the session store. If you do not want that but prefere to allways have a fresh `myAttribute` in the get part you should have instead :

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myHomePage(Model model) {
        MyAttribute myAttribute = new MyAttribute(); // create a fresh myAttribute
        //some changes in model attribute
        model.addAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
        returns ("myFirstPageView");
    }
```

As a reference, here is a full controller using `SessionAttribute` (from `PetClinic` example)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}/edit")
@SessionAttributes(types = Owner.class)
public class EditOwnerForm {

    private final Clinic clinic;


    @Autowired
    public EditOwnerForm(Clinic clinic) {
        this.clinic = clinic;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId, Model model) {
        Owner owner = this.clinic.loadOwner(ownerId);
        model.addAttribute(owner);
        return "owners/form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Owner owner, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new OwnerValidator().validate(owner, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "owners/form";
        }
        else {
            this.clinic.storeOwner(owner);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/owners/" + owner.getId();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you say that I dont have to use the @ModelAttribute("myAttribute") method? And just use the @SessionAttribute..

Comment: @Jose A `@ModelAttribute` annotated method pre-populates the model before calling the `RequestMapping` ones. And a ModelAttribute parameter is taken from session store if it exists, else it is created. So your `ModelAttribute` method was allready useless.

Comment: Than you for your support. I tried as you said by adding it in session and removing ModelAttribute from method signature of myHomePage. But when the second method is called, i am getting follwoing exception: org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'myAttribute'
 at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:103) ~[org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]

Comment: if I put the below method in Conroller, the above exception is not seen:
 @ModelAttribute("myAttribute")
 public MyAttribute getMyAttribute() {
  return new MyAttribute();
 }
But in this case, this method is getting executed on call of second method and new model attribute is populated.

Answer (score 0):

This was because of using http insted of https in the url. Whith https the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

you can put the object into session, then use @SessionAttribute to retrieve it, since session can be used to across requests.